# Клонируется не весь репозиторий

Tags: git, git-clone

Почему при написании команды

```
git clone git://myrepo.com/project.git
```

у меня клонируется только одна ветка master, хотя на удаленном репозитории у меня несколько?

Comment: Ну так переключись в склонированном репозитории на нужную ветку и она из удаленного подтянется.

Comment: @u_mulder это вообще как? Невозможно переключиться на ветку, которая не подтянута, гит так не умеет.

Comment: @PavelMayorov умеет. Я всю жизнь так делаю. `git clone REPO` и затем сразу `git checkout develop` (или любая другая ветка) и всё вполне работает.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Лол, ну ты хоть попробовал прежде чем писать такую чушь.

Comment: @u_mulder чтобы попробовать, нужно ввести команду, а команды-то для этого действия и нет. щас попробую ваш checkout develop...

Comment: Эта команду тебе уже написал @АлексейШиманский

Comment: @u_mulder вот я создал ветку 111 в удалённом репозитории, и написал `git checkout 111`. А он мне в ответ - "error: pathspec '111' did not match any file(s) known to git"

Comment: Так посмотри с помощью `git branch -a` какие ветки у тебя есть.

Comment: @PavelMayorov вы, как я понимаю, немного о другом. Вы создали ветку **после того** как склонировали репу. Это другое.... Либо вообще не в той папке)

Comment: @u_mulder вы же пишете: *"и она из удаленного подтянется".* А она не подтянулась. О чём я и пишу, переключаться можно только на те ветки, которые уже подтянуты.

Comment: @u_mulder да действительно, вы правы... Спасибо

Answer (score 4):

Локально и не должны копироваться все ветки. По умолчанию вы на ветке master или main.

Можно, конечно, извлечь информацию об удалённых ветках

```
git fetch
```

и потом переключиться.

Можно просто посмотреть список удалённых веток через `git branch -a`

и дальше сделать `checkout` на нужную.

---

А локально отображаются только локальные ветки, что логично.

Answer (score 2):

Проверьте свой .gitconfig в домашней директории, возможно там есть какие-то лишние настройки. Однако, если таких настроек нет - скорее всего, вы просто немного недопоняли произошедшее.

По умолчанию репозиторий клонируется целиком, со всеми ветками, тэгами и коммитами. Однако, локальные ветки не создаются, вместо этого удалённые ветки превращаются в так называемые remote-tracking branches (ветки отслеживания remote, т.е. удалённых репозиториев), по-русски ветки наблюдения или следящие ветки. Они находятся в отдельном пространстве имён и имеют префикс, соответствующий имени удалённого репозитория (по умолчанию origin).

Для примера допустим, что в удалённом репозитории была ветка `foo`, полное имя `refs/heads/foo`. В таком случае в локальном репозитории она станет `origin/foo`, полное имя `refs/remotes/origin/foo`.

Переключиться на такую ветку можно командой `git checkout foo`, но только если вы ещё не создали локальную ветку с тем же именем. Кстати, более полная форма этой команды - `git checkout origin/foo -b foo`.

Comment: ,а вот эти **remote-tracking branches** они фактически копируются в локальный репозиторий? Т.е после `git checkout origin/foo -b foo` ветка _foo_ будет втягиваться из удаленной ветки(с удаленного сервера), либо же из ее уже локальной копии в склонированном репозитории? Т.е к примеру, я склонировал удаленный себе на машину, создались эти **remote-tracking branches**... Дальше если у меня не будет доступа к удаленному, смогу я сделав `git checkout origin/foo -b foo` получить ветку _foo_ удаленного???

Comment: есть еще один вопрос: как восстановить удаленный bare репозиторий по локальному?

Comment: @Njyb клонирование подразумевает что в результате у вас полная копия репозитория. Так что да, все  remote-tracking branches находятся у вас локально и могут быть использованы без доступа к удалённому репозиторию.

Comment: @Njyb для восстановления bare-репозитория просто клонируйте его из локального с ключом --bare, после чего создаёте в нём все нужные ветки. Или же создайте пустой репозиторий (вообще пустой, без коммитов!) и запуште туда все ветки из локального. Тут есть некоторые хитрости, но это уже тема для отдельного вопроса, в не для комментария.

Comment: Как правильно работать с fetch? К примеру я склонировал репозиторий, ответвился и по идее каждое утро должен обновлять свою локальную копию, дабы потом слить свою ветку со свежей веткой разработки и затем все это запушить в удаленный? Так это делается по уму?

Comment: @Njyb зависит от проекта. На вашем личном проекте вы сами знаете когда нужно сделать fetch, нет нужды в расписании. Если проект делается командой, то существуют git flow, github flow, gitlab flow, trunk based development, несколько подходов к непрерывной интеграции всего этого и отдельно есть flow разработки ядра linux.